# How to pass an instance of a class to another class in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a class that looks like this

```
public class TableMapper<TSource>
{
    ....
    ....
    public TableMapper(IQueryExtractor queryExtractor, string tableAliasPrefix = null)
    {
        QueryExtractor = queryExtractor;

        TableAliasPrefix = tableAliasPrefix;
    }

    ....
    ....
}
```

I create an instance of this class from within another class like so

```
public class CustomerMapper : ReportTemplate
{
    private readonly IQueryExtractor QueryExtractor;

    private readonly TableMapper<Customer> customerMapper;

    private readonly TableMapper<Client> clientMapper;

    public CustomerMapper(DbContext context)
        : base(new QueryBuilder(), new QueryExecutor(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        QueryExtractor = new QueryExtractor(context);

        customerMapper = new TableMapper<Customer>(QueryExtractor, "Customer");

        clientMapper = new TableMapper<Client>(QueryExtractor);
    }

    public List<IReportRelation> ReportRelations
    {

        return new List<IReportRelation>
            { 
                new ReportRelation
                {
                    ForeignColumn = customerMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.ClientId),
                    LocalColumn = clientMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.Id),
                },
            };
    }

}
```

As you can see in the `ReportRelations` method, I return list of `ReportRelation` implementations. What I need to do is add 2 more public properies to my `IReportRelation` interface and `ReportRelation` implementation to hold instance of my `TableMapper<TSource>` class

How can I define a public variable in `IReportRelation` interface that will have a copy/instance of `customerMapper` property?

Here is how my `IReportRelation` definition

```
public interface IReportRelation
{
    //Here I need to add an instance that hold the localTable
    //something like this TableMapper<TSource> LocalMapper
    //something like this TableMapper<TSource> ForeignMapper

    IReportColumn ForeignColumn { get; set; }

    IReportColumn LocalColumn { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATED**

After Tim's suggestion below I change my code to the following

```
public interface IReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign>
{
    TableMapper<TLocal> LocalMapper { get; set;}

    TableMapper<TForeign> ForeignMapper { get; set; }

    IReportColumn ForeignColumn { get; set; }

    IReportColumn LocalColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my `CustomerMapper` class my function will look like this

```
public List<IReportRelation<Customer,Client> ReportRelations
    {

        return new List<IReportRelation<Customer,Client>>
            { 
                new ReportRelation<Customer,Client>
                {
                                    LocalMapper = this.customerMapper,
                    ForeignMapper = this.clientMapper,
                    ForeignColumn = customerMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.ClientId),
                    LocalColumn = clientMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.Id),

                },
            };
    }
```

But the problem is that `ReportRelations` will always return a list of `IReportRelation<Customer,Client>`. What if I want to return mix list something like this for example

```
    public List<IReportRelation<Customer,Client> ReportRelations
    {

        return new List<IReportRelation<Customer,Client>>
            { 
                new ReportRelation<Customer,Client>
                {
                                    LocalMapper = this.customerMapper,
                    ForeignMapper = this.clientMapper,
                    ForeignColumn = customerMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.ClientId),
                    LocalColumn = clientMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.Id),

                },

                new ReportRelation<Customer,Team>
                {
                    LocalMapper = this.customerMapper,
                    ForeignMapper = this.teamMapper,
                    ForeignColumn = customerMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.TeamId),
                    LocalColumn = clientMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.Id),
                },
            };
    }
```

Comment: You could use a property.  Interfaces don't have variables.

Comment: How can I define my property to store instance of my `customerMapper`

Comment: `TableMapper<TSource> LocalMapper { get; set; }`, the same way you define other properties.  I'm a little confused as to what the challenge is here.

Comment: you could create an base class that inherit from this interface, and in the base class constructor you can enforce the user to init this property.

Comment: I guess the problem comes from `Client` and `Customer` not being fixed.

Comment: Tim, I updated my question with you suggestion. But the problem is that ReportRelations will always return a list of IReportRelation<Customer,Client>. What if I want to return mix list??? please see my updated question

Comment: @Jaylen - Then you'll need two separate lists.

Comment: Tim, that would defeat the purpose. Is there alternative solution where the returned list can be mixed?

Comment: @Jaylen - perhaps have a base interface that `IReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign>` would implement and make the `List<T>` of that base interface.  I'm not 100% sure that would even work since generics are involved though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix different generic type parameters in a list. A common solution to this problem is to have a non generic base interface and to derive the generic one from it.

```
public interface ITableMapper
{
    // Use Sytem.Type arguments where appropriate and
    // the object type instead of generic types
    ...
}

public class TableMapper<TSource> : ITableMapper
{
    ...
}
```

```
public interface IReportRelation
{
    ITableMapper LocalMapper { get; }
    ITableMapper ForeignMapper { get; }

    IReportColumn ForeignColumn { get; set; }
    IReportColumn LocalColumn { get; set; }
}

public interface IReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign> : IReportRelation
{
    new TableMapper<TLocal> LocalMapper { get; set; }
    new TableMapper<TForeign> ForeignMapper { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign> : IReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign>
{
    ITableMapper IReportRelation.LocalMapper { get { return LocalMapper; } }
    ITableMapper IReportRelation.ForeignMapper { get { return ForeignMapper; } }

    public TableMapper<TLocal> LocalMapper { get; set; }
    public TableMapper<TForeign> ForeignMapper { get; set; }

    public IReportColumn ForeignColumn { get; set; }
    public IReportColumn LocalColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to implement the non generic interface explicitly. This hides it when working directly with the class.

Now you can have a `List<IReportRelation>` and fill in `ReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign>` objects having different generic type arguments.

You can find this pattern in the .NET Framework Libary. See `IList<T> : IList`, `IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable` and so on ...

Comment: I have never seen such a pattern. That looks pretty useful. I guess that's the difference between having 45k and 1k points ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume `Client` and `Customer` could change. Here what you could do:

```
public interface IReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign>
{
    TableMapper<TLocal> LocalMapper { get; set; }
    TableMapper<TForeign> ForeignMapper { get; set; }

    IReportColumn ForeignColumn { get; set; }
    IReportColumn LocalColumn { get; set; }
}

public class ReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign> : IReportRelation<TLocal, TForeign>
{
    public TableMapper<TLocal> LocalMapper { get; set; }
    public TableMapper<TForeign> ForeignMapper { get; set; }

    public IReportColumn ForeignColumn { get; set; }
    public IReportColumn LocalColumn { get; set; }
}
```

And for your `CustomMapper` class

```
public class CustomerMapper : ReportTemplate
{
    ...

    public List<IReportRelation<Customer, Client>> ReportRelations
    {
        return new List<IReportRelation<Customer, Client>>
        { 
            new ReportRelation<Customer, Client>
            {
                LocalMapper = this.customerMapper,
                ForeignMapper = this.clientMapper,
                ForeignColumn = customerMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.ClientId),
                LocalColumn = clientMapper.GetReportColumn(x => x.Id)
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check my updated question as I did this but the problem is that I need to return a list of mix sources it is not always going to be <Customer,Client>  it will change

Comment: I don't see any way of having such a list.

Comment: Is there a way to return a list of dictionary?

Comment: @Jaylen - Yes.  `List<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>>`

Comment: How would I add `new ReportRelation<Customer, Client>` or `new ReportRelation<Customer, Team>` to the Dictionary?